# Can you identify immersionRC transmitter crystal?

Tags: crystal

Please identify this crystal. It's from immersionRC 600mW video transmitter. Labeled S80003H. I have another one labeled S80009F from same brand transmitter 100mW, they are same, whats difference?
[image: immersionRC 600mW transmitter crystal]

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't seen anything with that exact marking,
I speculate that it is perhaps a cylinder type 8.000 MHz crystal oscillator,
more or less interchangeable with the 8.000 MHz 
[AB308-8.000MHZ](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/3/ab308-47627.pdf),
[MCRJ308000F18300HZH](http://www.newark.com/pdfs/datasheets/spc/Ta-1114.pdf),
[ECS-80-18-10X](http://www.ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-3x10X%203x9X.pdf),
etc.

I speculate that the S80003H is perhaps exactly the part model as the S80009F,
but manufactured in a different week.
And so with exactly the same part number
except for the [date code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/semiconductor_package#Date_code).

If, hypothetically, this company uses
[International Rectifier's date code system](http://www.irf.com/package/partmarking.pdf),
then

- "3H" indicates the 8th week of 2003 or 2013, and
- "9F" indicates the 6th week of 1999 or 2009.